# Selenium xpath element attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I´m trying to get the attribute from the " data-nice-url" element my html looks like this:

```
<div class="car-thumb-item clickable vehicle " data-include_settings="true" data-nice_url="/privatleasing/Citro%c3%abn-Berlingo/eHDi-90-Seduction-E6G" data-id="34285" style="display: block;">
<div class="car-thumb-brand">Citroën</div>
<div class="car-thumb-model">Berlingo </div>
<div class="car-thumb-variant">eHDi 90 Seduction E6G</div>
<div class="car-thumb-image" style="background-image: url('https://online.leasingcar.dk/Views/Public/GetPDFDocument.aspx?imageId=18442')"/>
<div class="car-thumb-details clearfix">
<div class="car-thumb-specs">1. ydelse 24.838 Kr. | 36 mdr. | 15.000 Km     | Inkl. service | Inkl. moms</div>
</div>
```

The result I want is: `"/privatleasing/Citro%c3%abn-Berlingo/eHDi-90-Seduction-E6G"`

The following xpath seems to work in Firepath and highlights what I want:

```
//div[@class='car-thumb-item clickable vehicle   ']/@data-nice_url
```

But when I run the code it times out everytime? My code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest


class DataTest(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://www.leasingcar.dk/privatleasing")

def testData(self):
    driver = self.driver
    urlXpath = "//div[@class='car-thumb-item clickable vehicle   ']/@ data-nice_url"

    carLinks = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver:  driver.find_elements_by_xpath(urlXpath))

    for car in carLinks:
        print car

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rely on the presence of `data-nice_url` attribute and a `vehicle` class:

```
vehicle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-nice_url and contains(@class, "vehicle")]')
print(vehicle.get_attribute("data-nice_url")
```

With `WebDriverWait` applying to your code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
car_links = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-nice_url and contains(@class, "vehicle")]'))

for car in carLinks:
    print car
```

And, as an alternative, a CSS selector:

```
vehicle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.vehicle[data-nice_url]')
print(vehicle.get_attribute("data-nice_url")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get an element by XPath and then use `WebElement`'s method `get_attribute` to retrieve the information you need.

Example:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(urlXpath)
nice_url = element.get_attribute("data-nice_url")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlXpath = //div[@class="car-thumb-item clickable vehicle"] 
nice_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath(urlXpath).get_attribute("data-nice_url")
```